# Stuck in the calculations of matrix sizes for a CNN

Tags: math, deep-learning, classification, conv-neural-network

In my CNN architecture for binary classification, I have 2 convolutional layers, 2 maxpooling layers, 2 batchnormalization operations, 1 RELu and 1 fullyconnected layer.

***Case1***: When the number of channels, `d=1`: In the first layer an input of size `[28*28*d]`, `d=1` channel is convolved with `M_1=20` number of filters applied over all the input channels of size `(f_h x f_w x d) = [3x 3x1]` having the step size (stride) as 1 that creates a feature map of size `{(h-f_h+1) x (w - f_w +1)x d x M_1}` = `(28-3 +1)x(28-3+1)x1x 20 = [25x 25x 20]`.

The second convolutional layer contains twice the number of filters = 40 of same size `[3x 3 x 1]`. So, the number of parameters becomes `[23 * 23 * 1 * 40]` as the output from the second convolutional layer. So total number of parameters =  `[25x 25x 20]+  [23 * 23 *  40]`

***Case 2***: When `d=2` and all other sizes are same. The filter size become `[3 x 3 x 2]`. The output of the first convolutional layer will contain: `(28-3 +1)x(28-3+1)x2 x20 = [25x 25x 40]`.

For the second convolutional layer, the output will contain `[23 x 23 x 2 x 40]` parameters.

**Question )** Is my calculation for each case above correct? What will be the input to the fully connected layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a convolutional layer, the no. of channels in the filter is kept equal to the number of channels of the input. Also, the no. of channels in the filter does not affect the size of the output. The size of the output is given by :

```
height = (input_height - filter_height + 1) (Assuming no padding and stride = 1)
width = (input_width - filter_width + 1)
channels = no. of filters
```

So for your question :

**Case 1 (d=1) :**

Conv layer #1

```
Input : 28 x 28 x 1, Filter : 3 x 3 x 1, #filters : 20
So your output becomes (28-3+1) x (28-3+1) X #filters = 26 x 26 x 20
```

The above output becomes your input for the second convolutional layer, which leads to :

Conv layer #2

```
Input : 26 x 26 x 20, Filter : 3 x 3 x 20, #filters : 40 (You mentioned size of filter as 3x3x1, but it should be 3x3x20 since the no. of filter channels = no. of input channel)
Output for this layer : (26-3+1) x (26-3+1) x #filters = 24 x 24 x 40
```

**Case 2 (d=2) :** 
*For this case also, the output of the two conv layers will be the same as above, since the output does not depend on the number of channels*

Conv layer #1

```
Input : 28 x 28 x 2, Filter : 3 x 3 x 2, #filters : 20
So your output becomes (28-3+1) x (28-3+1) X #filters = 26 x 26 x 20
```

Conv layer #2

```
Input : 26 x 26 x 20, Filter : 3 x 3 x 20, #filters : 40
Output for this layer : (26-3+1) x (26-3+1) x #filters = 24 x 24 x 40
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have 2 concerns, can you please clarify?(1) Can you please mention the number of parameters as well? (2)Also, does having maxpooling layer affect these numbers? I have read that maxpooling reduces the dimensions, and in my case I have 2 maxpooling layers after each conv. layer.  Each maxpooling is of size 3 and stride 2. It will be very kind of you if you could explain these two points.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors. The first one is trivial and it's about the size of the output of the first layer, as it should be `26x26x20` not `25x25x20`, because a kernel size of `3` without padding will make you lose just a pixel from each edge.

The more important issue in your reasoning happens in your calculation of the number of parameters of the second convolutional layer. Plain, usual convolution requires you to also consider the depth: let's assume you have a convolutional layer with `m` output featuremaps `f_1,...,f_m` and inputs of size `h*w*d`. Let's also assume that the convolution kernel is of spatial dimension `k*k`. Then a pixel `x` in any of the output maps, say, `f_j`, will be the result of a `3d` convolution between the input of size `h*w*d` and a kernel of size `k*k*d`. Therefore, the convolutional layer has `k*k*d*m` parameters. This means that in your case:

```
input of layer: 26x26x20
number of filters in layer: 40
number of parameters: 26x26x20x40
```

The same can be said about your reasoning with `d=2`: the second convolution will have `20x40` output maps,not `2x40`.

Comment: Thank you for answering about the other part of the question--number of parameters. It is a bit unclear, can you please elaborate for each step for the two cases? Also, would maxpooling affect these numbers?I have 2 maxpooling layers.  In my case each maxpooling is of size 3 and stride 2.

Comment: @Sm1 Maxpooling itself doesn't have any parameters. If you place it between the convolutional layers it will reduce the number of necessary parameters in the second convolution. I think the best way for you to make sense of all that is to find the number of parameters via the deep learning framework you are using (e.g. a parameters() function of some kind). Note that most frameworks will assume a bias by default in convolutions, so you might have one extra parameter.